# Is KAnnotator working in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kannotator

I have installed KAnnotator (0.2.1205) in Android Studio (0.5.8). It generated the annotations, but it seems to me that they are not used, or I not understand it.

There is annotation:

```
<item name='android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder setContentTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)'>
    <annotation name='org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull'/>
</item>
```

But still, I have to write:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle(myTitle)!!
```

Do I have to manually attach the annotations? If so, where?

Comment: If you are using a Gradle-based project, then, unfortunately, the new Android Studio ignores external annotations. There's no workaround for this at the moment, but we'll come up with something

Comment: @AndreyBreslav Yes, it is Grandle-based. Could I use Idea instead? (Or is there a difference in functionality between Idea and Android Studio?)

Comment: I think you can use IDEA instead of Android Studio. Not really sure about the differences in functionality, but most of AS capabilities are available in IDEA